# GrapdDB query with json-LD output

Tags: json-ld, graphdb

is it possible to use GrapdDB to create a curl SPARQL query with json-LD output (no export)?

Which parameter do I have to insert in the URL?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

In order to get results in JSON-LD format you should add the following to the URL:

```
Accept=application%2Fld%2Bjson
```

Please note that only `DESCRIBE` and `CONSTRUCT` queries support the JSON-LD format.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add a HTTP header and I don't think adding a query param will work. Eg:

```
curl -HAccept:application/ld+json http://localhost:7200/repositories/some/statements?query=CONSTRUCT...
```

Unfortunately, you can't specify a context or frame to be used for the output.